# Cannot connect to L2TP-VPN server in iPhone

Tags: networking, iphone, vpn

I've setup L2TP-VPN Settings in iPhone with iOS 4.2.1. But when I try to connect to the VPN server, I cannot connect And my phone shows  the following error:

> The L2TP-VPN server did not respond.
>   try reconnecting. if the problem
>   continues, verify your settings and
>   contact your administrator.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that solved this problem for me. The resolution was to change the encryption settings on the L2TP server. Check out: http://apple-ipad-tablet-help.blogspot.com/2010/12/ipad-vpn-fails-to-connect-on-ios-421.html

Note that the solution there may be specific to SonicWall firewalls used as VPN servers. Luckily for me, I use a SonicWall, so the solution worked perfectly for me. Your mileage may vary, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but unfortunately the link is dead.